# Using EntityManager while in full integration test doesn't commit changes in time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a TestUtil class which helps me insert some data during full integration tests. It has the following method:

```
@Autowired private AccountRepository accountRepo;
@Autowired private EntityManager entityManager;


    @Transactional
public URI createAccountAndReturnAccountURI(TestRestTemplate restTemplate, String userName, String password) {
    HttpHeaders headers = getApplicationJsonHeaders();

    String emailAddress = userName + "@bla.com";
    String accountRequestBody =
            "{\"username\": \"" + userName + "\", \"password\": \"" + password + "\", \"emailAddress\": \""
                    + emailAddress + "\", \"roles\": [\"" + Constants.ROLE_USER + "\"]}";
    HttpEntity<String> accountEntity = new HttpEntity<>(accountRequestBody, headers);
    URI accountLocation = restTemplate.postForLocation(Constants.ACCOUNTSPATH, accountEntity);
    if (accountLocation == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to setup test, accountLocation was null.");

    //Technically this is not a full integration test because then we'd have to receive emails,
    //extract the activation token and make a call to activate the acoount
    Account account = accountRepo.findByUsername(userName);
    account.setEnabled(true);
    entityManager.persist(account);
    entityManager.flush();

    return accountLocation;
}
```

As you perhaps understood from the comment in the code, normally an account has `enabled` set to `false` until the user validates their account with a token in their email address. It would be a bit much to extract this token from the email and use it to activate each account before continuing with the test, so I tried to manually change the `enabled` property of the account. This however doesn't throw any exceptions but it doesn't change the `enabled` property to `true` IN TIME. If I set a breakpoint on the last row, `enabled` is still `false` in the database. If I kill the whole application at that moment, `enabled` becomes `true` in the database, I suppose it then actually ends the transaction. But that is too late for me. Is there any way to do this? Or am I forced to go the long way around by somehow monitoring a testing email address for inbound activation emails? There is another intermediate solution to query the token table and getting it from there but that gets pretty ugly too.

Btw I have tried to begin and commit the transaction (`entityManager.getTransaction().begin();`) but then I get the exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead`